# Как привязать скрипт к действию php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на wordpress+woocommerce с установленным плагином сравнения **YITH WooCommerce Compare**. Действие вызываемое при нажатии на кнопку сравнения ['yith-woocompare-add-product'](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-compare/).

```
/**
         * The action used to add the product to compare list
         *
         * @var string
         * @since 1.0.0
         */
        public $action_add = 'yith-woocompare-add-product';
```

Вопрос: как привязать к этому действию скрипт появления блока (который изначально скрыт), т.е. чтобы блок был все время видим пока в сравнении что-то есть и исчезать, когда из сравнения все удалено?

```
<script>
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery(function($){
                    "use strict";
                    $('#fix-bot').show();
                    });
        console.log("fix-bot show");
        </script>
```

Comment: Первый код с php другой js. пишите всё на php т.е. если есть в сравнение что то показывать если нет то нет.

Comment: @Naumov не в обиду - вроде что-то и наговорили, но ничего по существу.. я ж надеюсь, вы обратили внимание на чем построен интернет-магазин, про какой плагин речь или вы считаете, что я `js` от `php` отличить не могу

Comment: Насколько мне известно можно написать функцию в теме или же плагин, который будет исполнятся на определенные действия. 
Можно писать на https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: А можно просто на хук повесить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно зацепиться за эвент самого плагина:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on( 'yith_woocompare_open_popup', function( e, data ) {
        // Тут ваш код
    });
} );
```

PS: возможно, я не прав в написании названия события, сейчас посмотрю по коду.

Comment: Посмотрел по коду - событие написал верно. В плагине их всего три: `yith_woocompare_open_popup`, `yith_woocompare_product_removed`, `yith_woocompare_page_refreshed` - если понадобится